# Serializing data from a table containing varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server-2005

What is the best way to serialize data from an SQL Server 2005 table? The table has assorted columns like datetime, bigint, decimal, varchar, varchar(max).

The plan is to dump the data to a file, send the file to another server, then put the data into the table of that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a range of options:

1. Use Bulk Copy (BCP) to dump the data out to a file and BCP to reload it on the other server.
2. Take a backup of the database, ship the DB files and extract the required data at the other end.
3. Create an SSIS to output the data to a file (SSIS supports a range of formatting options) and then create an SSIS package to Import the data.

Unless you planned on changing / merging the data the other end, I would BCP / Backup. If I was planning on performing some merge / transforms at the remote end, I would probably tend to use SSIS.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like BCP or SSIS is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you put just the path of that file into the table? if you store the file into a Sql table you need to "deserialize" it before you can work on it